# Free 2d CAD for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, cad

Okay I've looked, and I've looked but for the life of me I can't find a free 2d CAD program that is compatible for Ubuntu. I need it to be free but allow me to type in exact measurements for the sides and angles. Also I can't work with something that has a layer limit because I'm designing a forty floor building. Please need one A.S.A.P.

Thanks,
ShockWave

Answer (score 1):

I like [LibreCad for 2D](http://librecad.org/) work and [FreeCad for 3D](http://www.freecadweb.org/) work. They work pretty nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried [Draftsight](http://www.3ds.com/products/draftsight/free-cad-software/)? Is powerful but **not** free software.

Comment: Yes in fact I have and it might just be me because I'm rushing to get the floor plan done but how do you make exact measurements in draftsight?

Comment: Everything in Draftsight is almost identical to ACAD 2D. For exact measurements  use "inquiry".